# Multiple JOIN with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following database:

==================

## product

product_id

name

price

==================

## orderItem

orderItem_id

**product**

**order**

amount

cost

==================

## order

order_id

**store**

==================

## store

store_id

**country**

name

==================

## country

country_id

name

---

Where a **Country** have many **Stores**, a **Store** have many **Orders**, an **Order** have many **OrderItems** and an **OrderItem** is about one **Product**.

With this query I retrieve all **Products** with **OrderItems**:

```
SELECT p.name, sum(o.amount) as total
              FROM SupplierBundle:Product p
              LEFT JOIN SupplierBundle:OrderItem o
              WHERE p.id = o.product
              GROUP BY p.id
```

And works fine, but what I want is all **Products** with **OrderItems** given a **Country**. I try with this but doesn't work, **return 0 rows**:

```
SELECT p.name,
       sum(oi.amount) as total,
       FROM SupplierBundle:OrderItem oi
       JOIN SupplierBundle:Product p
       WITH oi.product = p.id
       JOIN SupplierBundle:Order o
       WITH oi.order = o.id
       JOIN SupplierBundle:Store s
       WITH o.store = s.id
       WHERE s.id = :countryId
```

I also tried with all **OrderItems** of one **Store** but nothing change:

```
SELECT p.name,
       sum(oi.amount) as total,
       FROM SupplierBundle:OrderItem oi
       JOIN SupplierBundle:Product p
       WITH oi.product = p.id
       JOIN SupplierBundle:Order o
       WITH oi.order = o.id
       JOIN SupplierBundle:Store s
       WITH o.store = 1
```

The problem seems like I can access relation entities of **OrderItem** but no for "joined" entities.

Any solution?

I'm using Doctrine2 with Symfony2:

```
$dqlQuery = 'SELECT ...';
$query = $em->createQuery($dqlQuery);
$query->setParameter('countryId', 1);
$products = $query->getResult();
```

**Edit:**

Added OrderItem entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="OrderItem")
 */
class OrderItem
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="product")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="orderItems")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cost", type="integer")
 */
private $cost;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer")
 */
private $amount;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy your orderItem entity? I guess the error is in this relationship.

Comment: A stupid question... Have you put `* @ORM\Entity` under `* @ORM\Table(name="OrderItem")`?

Comment: The relationship between "product" and "orderItem" shouldn't be OneToOne?

Comment: Yes, I only remove useless code. I think I have the solution. With Product and Order work because the __toString() method return his id. In store and country I was returning the name. So I change that and work, but I don't know if then I can need this __toString() returning the name of the entity :(